Holomorphic non vanishing modular form
Let $\mathcal{O}(\mathcal{H})^\times$ be the multiplicativee group of holomorphic functions on the Poincaré half-plane $\mathcal{H}$ that do not vanish there.
Let $j(g,z)=(cz+d)$ and $gz=(az+b)/(cz+d)$ when $g$ is the matrix $\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix} a & b\\ c & d\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$ and $z\in\mathcal{H}$.
For which values of $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, $k\neq 0$, are there functions $a\in\mathcal{O}(\mathcal{H})^\times$ such that,
$$
\forall g\in\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})\quad\forall z\in\mathcal{H}\quad a(gz)=j(g,z)^ka(z) ?
$$
Necessarily, $k$ is even and $a$ is periodic with period $1$, so I can talk about regularity at infinity.
If I add a condition of meromorphy at infinity, the function $a$ is necessarily a modular function of weight $k$, the formula $k/12$ implies that the order of $f$ at infinity is $k/12$ and $k$ must be a multiple of $12$: in this case, $\Delta^{k/12}$ is suitable where $\Delta$ is the unique weight $12$ primitive form with level $1$.
So let's write $k=12q+r$ with $r\in\{2,4,6,8,10\}$. If there exists a function $a$ as a solution, then the function $a/\Delta^q$, which is an element of $\mathcal{O}(\mathcal{H})^\times$, is a solution to the problem by replacing $k$ with $r$.
Therefore, the question reduces to the following :

For $k\in\{2,4,6,8,10\}$, does it exist holomorphic functions $a$ that do not vanish on $\mathcal{H}$ (and are necessarily non-meromorphic at infinity) such that
$$
\forall g\in\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})\quad\forall z\in\mathcal{H}\quad a(gz)=j(g,z)^ka(z) ?
$$

NOTE - The question has been solved on MSE.

Welcome to MO! Please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory". I added this tag now. Regarding high-level tags, see https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1075/

Note: this was previously posted on MSE but received no answers: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4905539/11323

Do you mean $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ instead of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$? I don't know the answer for $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$, but for smaller congruence subgroups there are solutions, like powers of the Dedekind eta function.

Thank you François. yes, I mean $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$. Question edited for correction.
I am interested by your examples with smaller subgroups.

Nice question and nice solution!
